# Reputation history bug

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation-history

If I look at my own reputation history you'll see I've gained +15 today (until now :D ) but as you can see something is wrong:

[image]

I think the second event (the single duplicate +5 15 mins ago) should appear just once and not inside the '2 events' (which are 3!)

P.S.: oooook... Not anymore. After 15 minutes passed it just disappeared. So I imagine it's a temporary bug until something is automatically fixed?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you opened your reputation page, you had 3 upvotes on that question. It received one more upvote, and then you clicked to expand the "2 events". The data has been loaded using AJAX, which means you got the most up-to-date data. Refreshing the page should fix it.

Comment: Actually, when I accessed the reputation history tab was after I received the last upvote so it was not exactly that but... blame cache, probably.